# Installing front Door

Tags: installation, door-frame, old-house

I’m in Cleveland and are renovating 100 year old building. It has a retail shop on the street level and apartment above with commercial kitchen in the back of the building.

I’m replacing the front door and was going to replace the framing around it. Currently it has 4 x 4  on either side of the door. Neither reach the ceiling to carry any load and I can’t figure out why. Is this common in older housing?  I’m planning on replacing with 2 x 4 and properly putting in a header and help with the weight load of the wall. (Flat roof above, no building above this area)

Comment: It's not unusual if the wall isn't load bearing, unless it's a brick building in which case I would expect a lintel.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: sometimes 4x4 are used for decorative purpose

Comment: More info on the type of construction is necessary to give an answer with certainty.  Speculation would be that the construction provides a lintel over the opening for the door. The other wood and 4x4s you encountered are just the frame for the door and decorative as others stated.